# How do I deep clone XMLDocument Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, web

I'm creating a tool that parses XML file into XMLDocument object. I'm using browser implementation of xml parser e.g.:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
```

For some reason I should to have a copy of current XMLDocument object in another variable.

The question is - how to make deep clone of **parsed xml object**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [`cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), which `Document` inherits from `Node`:

```
var d2 = d.cloneNode(true);
```

Example:

```js
var d = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
  "<root><x><y></y></x></root>",
  "text/xml"
);
// Prove it's a deep clone by removing `y` from `x`:
console.log("d before", d.documentElement.firstChild.children.length);
var x = d.documentElement.firstChild;
var d2 = d.cloneNode(true);
x.removeChild(x.firstChild);
console.log("d after", d.documentElement.firstChild.children.length);
console.log("d2 after", d2.documentElement.firstChild.children.length);
```

---

[Eugene Ryabtsev points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47434798/how-do-i-deep-clone-xmldocument-object-in-javascript/47434899?noredirect=1#comment112294683_47434899) that this won't clone the information from the [prolog](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd), which is a good point.

As of this writing, the prolog information consists of:

- The XML version
- The `standalone` flag
- The encoding

Of those, only the `standalone` flag is relevant. The version is always 1.0 as of this writing (even if you give a different `1.x` value in the prolog, it's processed as an XML 1.0 document [per spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-VersionInfo)); and the encoding isn't relevant because we're dealing with a document in memory, not text we're deserializing from bytes.

But the standalone flag is indeed not copied by `cloneNode` (at least not on Chrome). If you also want to copy the standalone flag, add:

```
d2.xmlStandalone = d.xmlStandalone;
```

after `cloneNode`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not copy the prolog.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev - That's a good point. I've updated the answer to address that, but my XML knowledge is only so-so; does the update seem right?

Comment: It does not work for me, but I do a specific thing with the clone - indent it and serialize it, so for me just slapping a string prolog if none is present solves the issue. +1 for the analysis though. Fortunately, my documents have no processing instructions, so I don't have to think about these.

Answer (score 0):

It easier than you think. Just use Serializer and DOMParser.

```
cloneXML=function(xml) {
    var str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml.getRootNode())
    return new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml")
};
```